# Suppress spurious blank/newline created by a package

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

A package I use creates a spurious line break.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  ()(\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta})()% spurious line break
  ()(\tikzset{mytip /.tip = {Computer Modern Rightarrow}})()
\end{document}
```

Intended output:

```
()()()()()()
```

Current output

```
()(
)()()()()`
```

How can I suppress that? I tried wrapping the macro with `\rlap`, but that also removes the desired effects of the package.

Comment: isn't the usepgf thing supposed to be used in the preamble?

Comment: I agree with @David. Loading pgf libraries isn't that different from loading packages IMHO and should be done in the preamble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TikZ library files use blank lines very generously. A `\par` in vertical mode is ignored (well, not really, but the effects are irrelevant for the problem at hand). So you *must* load TikZ libraries in the preamble or *between* paragraphs.

One might think that doing

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  ()(\let\savedpar\par\let\par\relax\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}\let\par\savedpar)()% 
  ()(\tikzset{mytip /.tip = {Computer Modern Rightarrow}})()
\end{document}
```

would solve the problem. Alas, it doesn't, because spurious spaces appear. And, no, making the space into an ignored character wouldn't help, mainly because TikZ/PGF uses spaces in the key names.

Just do as I recommended before. And no, there's no way to solve this problem, except editing all library files to have no unprotected end-of-line and no blank line.

Comment: What a pity. This means, I cannot load the library on-demand from within my package, but rather have to delegate loading as a manual task to the user.